# How to solve $2^x+3^x=6^x$ for $x \in R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've thought about it in many ways, and finally come up with an algorithm to bring out an approximate answer.

Assume $f(x)=3^{-x}+2^{-x}-1$, then the answer for the equation is the root of $f(x)$. It is obvious that $f(x)$ decreases in the domain of $R$ with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=-\frac{1}{6}$, so we know the root is between $0$ and $1$. Hence, we can apply a binary algorithm to iteratively get closer and closer to the root.

The problem is that **is it possible to have an answer in exact form rather than an approximate value**. If so, how to solve it?

Comment: There isn't a solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams How could you tell whether an equation has analytic solution or arithmetic solution in such a short time? What's the secret sauce?

Comment: I wonder if even with non elementary functions, ther will be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer to the question but too long for a comment.**

As said in comments, I do not think that a closed form solution exists for the equation $$f(x)=2^x+3^x-6^x=0$$ However, I think that very good closed form approximations could be provided.

Instead of considering $f(x)$, take logarithms to define $$g(x)=\log(2^x+3^x)-\log(6^x)=\log(2^x+3^x)-x \log(6)$$ the graph of which being very close to linearity and use one single Newton iteration starting at $x_0$; this will give $$x_1=x_0-\frac{g(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}$$ So, let us start with $x_0=1$; this gives $$x_1=\frac{\log \left(\frac{3125}{108}\right)}{\log (72)}\approx 0.786841488533243$$ Do it again using $x_0=\frac{7868}{10000}$; this gives $$x_1=\frac{1967}{2500}-\frac{\log \left(2^{1967/2500}+3^{1967/2500}\right)-\frac{1967 \log
   (6)}{2500}}{\frac{2^{1967/2500} \log (2)+3^{1967/2500} \log
   (3)}{2^{1967/2500}+3^{1967/2500}}-\log (6)}\approx 0.787884883725292$$ Do it again using $x_0=\frac{78788}{100000}$; this gives $$x_1=\frac{19697}{25000}-\frac{\log
   \left(2^{19697/25000}+3^{19697/25000}\right)-\frac{19697 \log
   (6)}{25000}}{\frac{2^{19697/25000} \log (2)+3^{19697/25000} \log
   (3)}{2^{19697/25000}+3^{19697/25000}}-\log (6)}\approx 0.787884911025310$$ while, for fifteen significant digits, the exact solution is $0.787884911025870$

Comment: I admire the expression you typed, but this is clearly not answering (the highlighted part of) the question. It would be more helpful to provide arguments why an exact solution to this problem cannot exist. Beyond "the standard techniques for this kind of problem do not seem to lead to a solution", I know that is quite hard to do. For instance might it be the case that the solution is an algebraic number? And if so, must there necessarily be a proof that it is? But anyway, that kind of consideration is what OP is asking for.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen. I totally agree with all your points, be sure !